Should I buy a Tillandsia that is already flowering?
I am planning to buy a Tillandsia ionantha from a physical shop. There are many specimens to choose from, some of which are flowering. From my understanding, Tillandsia spp. are monocarpic, which means that they will die after flowering. Does this mean that it is a bad idea to buy a Tillandsia that is already flowering, since the plant will soon die after I buy it? I would not mind the plant dying if, before death, it produces seeds and/or offsets that I can use to produce more plants.

Yes, tillandsia die after flowering. A healthy plant will produce offsets but they can take years to mature.
Propagation from seed takes even longer but it is a great project if you have time and patience

I bought a T. ionantha that had flowered, died and made offsets - One randomly died but all are thriving on my kitchen windowsill now.
